# Do we have an awk / bash script to compare elements of a file line by line with another file having multiple delimiters?

Tags: unix, awk

I have a tab delimited file (say file1 having 4 columns) which has entries in the following fashion.

```
chr1    12145   12310   ref|DDX11L1,ref|NR_046018,ens|ENST00000518655,ens|ENST00000450305,ens|ENST00000456328,ens|ENST00000515242
```

I have another file (say file2) which comprises of elements which happen to be a subpart of the 4th column of file1

eg. `DDX11L1`

Is there a way to compare entries of file2 with file1 and if there is a partial match, like what is evident in the above mentioned case, produce an output similar to this -

```
chr1 12145  12310 DDX11L1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will tweak whitespace a bit, but perhaps:

```
$ cat file1
chr1 12145 12310 ref|DDX11L1,ref|NR_046018,ens|ENST00000518655,ens|ENST00000450305,ens|ENST00000456328,ens|ENST00000515242
chr2 12345 12310 ref|DDX12L1,ref|NR_046018,ens|ENST00000518655,ens|ENST00000450305,ens|ENST00000456328,ens|ENST00000515242
$ cat file2
DDX11L1
$ awk 'NR==FNR{split($4, a, "|"); $4=""; 
    for( i in a) b[a[i]] = $0; next} 
    { for( i in b ) if( match(i, $0)) {
          print b[i], $0; next}
}' file1 file2
chr1 12145 12310  DDX11L1
```

Note that this explicitly splits the 4th column on `|`, so there will be no partial match of a string like `1L1,ref|NR_`, but I suspect that is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

With awk, you can intermingle files and variable assignments, to alter the variables before starting to process the next file

```sh
gawk '
  ARGIND==1 {f2[$1]++; next}
  {
    for (i=4; i<=NF; i++)
      if ($i in f2) {
        print $1, $2, $3, $i
        break
      }
  }
' file2 FS='[\t,|]' file1
```

This uses GNU awk just for the ARGIND variable; the `NR==FNR` idiom breaks if the first file is empty.

Comment: This code is just working for one entry in file 2. Rest of the entries remain untouched. Same happened while I use the grep -f parameter as well.

Comment: chr8 100025987 100026152 VPS13B  is the result I get, while the format is exactly what is desired, there are close to 20,000 other items in file2 apart from VPS13B.

Comment: make sure the input files do not have `\r\n` line endings.